# Decide if there is modification or deletion

Tags: diff

I have two log files, I want to know differences in both log files. For example,

```
Track: X 0.4000 638 0.8000 1 3
Track: Y 0.5000 510 1.0000 1 5
Track: Y 0.5000 510 1.0000 1 4
Track: X 0.4000 638 0.8000 1 4
...
```

and

```
Track: X 0.4000 638 0.8000 1 5
Track: Y 0.5000 510 1.0000 1 5
Track: Y 0.5000 510 1.0000 1 4
Track: X 0.4000 638 0.8000 1 4
...
```

How to know if there is modification in an entry, or some entry is deleted.

Comment: `diff a.log b.log`?

Comment: That is fine sir. But how to decide if there is change or deletion. for example, in the shown instances of log files, it may happen that first entry of log1 is deleted in log2, and it can also happen that first entry of log1 is modified in log2.